# How to get text between div without any tag? <div class="obj-amount">15</div>

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I have this code in VBA and I want to extract '15' of `obj-amount` div class. Any suggestion?

```html
<div class="obj-amount">15<span class="unit">$</span></div>
```

```vba
Set divtags = oHtml.getElementsByClassName("obj-amount")(0).getElementsByTagName("obj-amount")
i = 0
For Each oElement In divtags
    Sheets("Data").Range("A" & i + 1) = divtags(i).innerText
    i = i + 1
Next oElement
```

Comment: from where you get 15? explain your code bit

Comment: Hi Irin, this is the info that I need to extract. It is value of product and it can vary. TIA.

Answer (score 0):

**Returning a collection and looping:**

You don't want to chain together `ByClassName` and `ByTagName`. Your selector inside is for classname alone and is sufficient to return a collection of elements with that classname.

You don't want to index at that level either, if after all elements with this class name for a loop. You want to `For Each` over the collection. Then in the loop you want to work with the loop variable, `oElement`; that'll mean you can start `i=1` and reduce the amount of code and calls for addition in the loop.

This will of course return the `$` which resides in the child `span` tag.

---

**Ways to avoid/remove the $ (or child `span` content):**

1. The simplest way to remove this, if unwanted, is to use `Replace$` on the `.innerText` during the loop.
2. If that text is not constant then you can do a replacement of `oElement.children(0).innerText` with `vbNullString` on the `.innerText`, or of `oElement.getElementsByTagName("span")(0).innertext`. The latter I think might have been what you were after doing (but it needed to be in the loop.).
3. You could also have done `oElement.FirstChild.NodeValue` without a replacement.

**N.B.**

Which methods are available to you will depend on how you declared `divtags` and `oElement`.

---

**Long text version:**

```
Set divtags = ohtml.getElementsByClassName("obj-amount") '<== collection matched by classname
i = 1
For Each oElement In divtags                 '<== loop each item in collection
    Worksheets("Data").Range("A" & i) = oElement.innerText
    'Worksheets("Data").Range("A" & i) = oElement.FirstChild.NodeValue
    'Worksheets("Data").Range("A" & i) = Replace$(oElement.innerText,"$", vbNullString)  '<==replacement if wanted
    'Worksheets("Data").Range("A" & i) = Replace$(oElement.innerText,oElement.children(0).innerText, vbNullString)  '<==replacement if wanted and first child text not constant
    'Worksheets("Data").Range("A" & i) = Replace$(oElement.innerText,oElement.getElementsByTagName("span")(0).innertext, vbNullString)  '<==replacement if wanted and child span text not constant
    i = i + 1
Next oElement
```

---

**Using `With` statement and Worksheet variable for legibility:**

I would probably put the worksheet into a variable and ensure I am working with `Worksheets` collection. I would also use `With` statement to hold reference to `oElement` inside the loop, so as to use dot accessor, `.` ,  for legibility:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
Set divtags = ohtml.getElementsByClassName("obj-amount") 
i = 1
For Each oElement In divtags  
    With oElement
        ws.Range("A" & i) = .FirstChild.NodeValue
        ws.Range("A" & i) = Replace$(.innerText, "$", vbNullString) 'next two lines are alternativeS based on need
        ws.Range("A" & i) = Replace$(.innerText, .Children(0).innerText, vbNullString)
        ws.Range("A" & i) = Replace$(.innerText, .getElementsByTagName("span")(0).innerText, vbNullString) 
    End With
    i = i + 1
Next oElement
```